# I accured to error in using share_plus from Gradle in flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle, share-plus

I want to use **share_plus** package in my prject
but when I Run application I accrued to error from **Gradle**
which show me

- What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project
  ':share_plus'.
- Could not resolve all files for configuration
  ':share_plus:classpath'.
- ...

in project :

> build.gradle

```
buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }
```

> gradle.wrapper

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

> error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':share_plus'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':share_plus:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-7.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.1/gradle-7.1.1.jar
   > Could not find lint-model-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-model/30.1.1/lint-model-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find builder-7.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/7.1.1/builder-7.1.1.jar
   > Could not find manifest-merger-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/30.1.1/manifest-merger-30.1.1.jar

   > Could not find sdk-common-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/30.1.1/sdk-common-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find sdklib-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/30.1.1/sdklib-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find repository-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools:repository:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/30.1.1/repository-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find gradle-api-7.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/7.1.1/gradle-api-7.1.1.jar
   > Could not find builder-test-api-7.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:7.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/7.1.1/builder-test-api-7.1.1.jar

   > Could not find ddmlib-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/30.1.1/ddmlib-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find aaptcompiler-7.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aaptcompiler/7.1.1/aaptcompiler-7.1.1.jar
   > Could not find aapt2-proto-7.1.1-7984345.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:7.1.1-7984345).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/7.1.1-7984345/aapt2-proto-7.1.1-7984345.jar

   > Could not find crash-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/30.1.1/crash-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find tracker-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/30.1.1/tracker-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find shared-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/30.1.1/shared-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find databinding-compiler-common-7.1.1.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/7.1.1/databinding-compiler-common-7.1.1.jar
   > Could not find databinding-common-7.1.1.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:7.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/7.1.1/databinding-common-7.1.1.jar

   > Could not find baseLibrary-7.1.1.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:7.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/7.1.1/baseLibrary-7.1.1.jar
   > Could not find layoutlib-api-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/30.1.1/layoutlib-api-30.1.1.jar

   > Could not find android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto/30.1.1/android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find android-device-provider-gradle-proto-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-gradle-proto:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-device-provider-gradle-proto/30.1.1/android-device-provider-gradle-proto-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto/30.1.1/android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto/30.1.1/android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto/30.1.1/android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto/30.1.1/android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find builder-model-7.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/7.1.1/builder-model-7.1.1.jar
   > Could not find dvlib-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/30.1.1/dvlib-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find common-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools:common:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/30.1.1/common-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find apkzlib-7.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/7.1.1/apkzlib-7.1.1.jar
   > Could not find protos-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/30.1.1/protos-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find signflinger-7.1.1.jar (com.android:signflinger:7.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/signflinger/7.1.1/signflinger-7.1.1.jar
   > Could not find zipflinger-7.1.1.jar (com.android:zipflinger:7.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/zipflinger/7.1.1/zipflinger-7.1.1.jar
   > Could not find annotations-30.1.1.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:30.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/30.1.1/annotations-30.1.1.jar
   > Could not find apksig-7.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:7.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/7.1.1/apksig-7.1.1.jar
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':share_plus' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':share_plus' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 31s
```

what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

First update flutter to latest version
Go into

> **Android/build.gradle**

Then change kotlin version

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21'
```

Then change

> **dependecies**

to

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
```

Then go to

> **android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties**
> change distribution URL

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

I've spent the last two days trying to solve this, with no results, so the solution i followed is this:

- open your pubspec.yaml file
- change the version of share_plus (for me it was 6.3.0, i roled it back to 4.0.4)
- execute `flutter pub get`
- execute `flutter run` (or simply click run in your IDE)

Comment: I fixed this error and the problem was for my internet connection and I changed my DNS and it has fiexed , right now I'm using share_plus 6.3.0 . However Thank you for your response.

Comment: I have also faced this issue when I just upgraded from Flutter 3.3 to 3.7. How I managed to solve this issue at my end is switching off my VPN.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, to fix it I: 
- upgraded my flutter to the latest stable version
- bumped the version of ext.kotlin_version to the latest version `ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21'`
- bumped the build.gradle: buildscript.dependencies.classpath to the latest `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'`
- bumped the version of my 
- updated the android>gradle>wrapper> grade-wrapper.properties file `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip`
- flutter clean
- flutter pub get

Answer (score 1):

ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.3' before
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21' after

this is work for me

Comment: This worked for me. In android/build.gradle under `buildscript` set `ext.kotlin_version` to `'1.8.21'` or above.